# How to define binSize or binCount in NED file

Tags: omnet++

I need to gather information about one signal in ten simulations.

I do it via `@statistic` and `@signal` defined in the NED file.

The problem is that in each of the 10 simulation histograms, a diffrent bin is created.

Do you know how to define the binSize of histogram in the NED file?

My NED File:

```
simple Generator
{

    parameters:
    @signal[GenStat](type="long");
    @statistic[GenStat](title="GenStat";source="GenStat";record=histogram; interpolationmode=none;);   

    gates:
        output out;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a histogram that gets generated in the OMNeT++ UI?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot directly define binSize from `@statistic` in NED file. However, you can specify desired number of bins:

```
@statistic[GenStat](title="GenStat";source="GenStat";record=histogram;numBins=20);
```

The `numBins` is a hint for result recorder. But quite often it results in the bin size equals to `100/numBins`.